# SQL Server In memory tables using tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, in-memory, in-memory-tables

I'm testing in memory tables on SQL 2014 and the execution plan for a particular query is showing a sort in tempdb.

[image]

The query has a join between two in memory tables (on a field that has a nonclustered index in both tables) and a group by with a few sums and counts - the server has plenty of RAM available.

Why is it the query being sorted in tempdb if the tables are"In Memory"?

I'm also wondering why is SQL Suggesting to create an index if the "create index" statement is not allowed on in memory tables.

Comment: Are you sure the upper table is "in memory"? Not sure if that would be shown as a table scan operator. I'd have expected an index scan.

Comment: You can have indexes defined in your `CREATE TABLE` statement ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133166%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) -> [CREATE TABLE - Memory optimized CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), see `<table_index>`)

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. yes, Im 100% sure the tables are inmemory - and I just found it weird that sql would suggest an index like that....but thats fine, ignore the index, any idea why the temp db spill?

Comment: Perhaps this helps explain? http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/02/05/memory-oltp-hekaton-sort-warnings/

Comment: Thanks @LesH , thas a good article but the tables don't have hash indexes, just non clustered indexes - also the statistics seem to be ok, as the "estimated number of rows" is the same as the "actual number of rows"

Answer (score 1):

This query is being run in interop mode. This uses the normal query processor except that it pulls data out of Hekaton tables. Otherwise there are no changes that I can think of.

The speedup that you obtain from Hekaton here is extremely limited if any.

You cannot use the `create index` statement but you can create indexes at table creation time.

Comment: but why is it using tempDb, can it be avoided? I mean whats the point of in memory tables if SQL has to use tempDb to sort the data?

Comment: You can use compiled procs to get the in-memory query pipeline. This will never spill. Not sure how memory is allocated there. If I remember correctly there were some limits. The Hekaton query pipeline is not made for bulk queries (yet). I think there is no hash or merge join at the moment. You might not like what you get.

Comment: The spill can possibly be avoided using standard query tuning techniques because this is not specific to Hekaton. Not sure what to recommend without query, query plan and schema.

Answer (score 1):

The data may be stored in memory, but the query processor can still only use the memory it's been given in it's memory grant to actually execute the query, if the memory required by the sort operator exceeds this because of a poor estimate by the optimizer, it will spill the same way as a query that uses disk based tables will.

Comment: makes sense, but there is plenty of memory available on the server and allocated to SQL Server

Comment: That may be the case, but a single query can't exceed it's memory grant while running and the grant can't be changed, so once it starts, it's stuck with the chunk of memory the optimizer decided it needed based on the information it had at the time. If this is too low, then you need to optimise the query or indexes/statistics so the optimizer can make a better decision for the memory grant.